# consultar base de datos desde otro modulo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

no sé si alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy tratando de hacer consultas a una base de datos, la conexión la tengo desde un modulo aparte el cual ya pude llamar en el script que estoy haciendo. pero al ejecutar me da este error 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor',no entiendo en que este fallando,

Esta es la función que tengo en modulo, donde hago la conexión a la base:

```
def BDSu():
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.dsn(
    "x.x.x.x",
    "xxxx",
    service_name="service_name"
    )

    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="usuario", password="contraseña",dsn=dsn_tns,encoding="UTF-8")    
        print(connection.version)
        return connection
    except Exception  as err:
        print("Error tratando de conectar con la base de datos")
        print(err)
```

y esta es la función que tengo en otro modulo, en el que importo la función anterior, y trato de ejecutar un archivo .sql desde este modulo, ya hice la prueba de ejecutar la consulta desde BDSu() y allí me corre bien, pero cuando lo hago en el otro modulo Consultas() no me corre, creo que estoy cometiendo un error pero no logro ubicarlo.

```
def Consultas():
    from con_Bases import BDSu as Su
   
    try:
        with open("./UnicaS4.sql",'r') as query:
            data = query.read()
        cursor = S4u.cursor()
        cursor.execute(data)
        datos = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close
        for row in datos:
            print(row)
    except Exception  as err:
        print("Error tratando de ejecutar consulta")
        print(err)
```

Comment: No creo que el código publicando tenga el error mencionado (pues ocurriría un NameError tal como está, y eso si intentas llamar a la función Consultas). Estás seguro de que hiciste BDSu() (o sea llamar a la función) antes de intentar crear el cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

falta tu llamada a la funcion

```
def Consultas():
    from con_Bases import BDSu as Su
    cursor =BDSu().cursor()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, si era eso.